# how to display current time and dates html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display the current time and date on my website but having issues because I need it displayed a certain way and with an hour added ahead.

For the first one I need it displayed like this:

```
20 Sep 2022 *current time* (12-hour format with am and pm)
```

second one:

```
20 Sep 2022 *current time +1hr* (12-hour format with am and pm)
```

I tried this code of Codepen but I need the time displayed after the date and it also shows as a short date on my site for some reason.

```js
function DateAndTime() {
  var dt = new Date();

  var Hours = dt.getHours();
  var Min = dt.getMinutes();
  var Sec = dt.getSeconds();

  var days = [
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    ""
  ];

  //strings
  var months = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec"
  ];

  if (Min < 10) {
    Min === "0" + Min;
  } //displays two digits even Min less than 10

  if (Sec < 10) {
    Sec === "0" + Sec;
  } //displays two digits even Sec less than 10

  var suffix = "AM"; //cunverting 24Hours to 12Hours with AM & PM suffix
  if (Hours >= 12) {
    suffix = "PM";
    Hours = Hours - 12;
  }
  if (Hours === 0) {
    Hours = 12;
  }

  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML =
    Hours + "Hours : " + Min + "Min : " + Sec + "Sec " + suffix + ".";
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML =
    days[dt.getDay()] +
    ", " +
    dt.getDate() +
    " " +
    months[dt.getMonth()] +
    " " +
    dt.getFullYear();
}

new DateAndTime();
setInterval("DateAndTime()", 1000);
```

the above code shows like this:

```
7Hours : 9Min : 47Sec PM.

, 20 Sep 2022
```

I need it displayed like this

```
20 Sep 2022 7:10 pm

20 Sep 2022 8:10 pm (one hour added to current time)
```

I'm pretty new to coding so sorry if it's a simple question trying to edit codes of Codepen seems to mess one thing or another up for me always.

thanks.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. You can use https://momentjs.com/  this library there are many date time conversion methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: @NiravBhoi That site says that MomentJS is no longer maintained and should not be used for new development. Perhaps it's time to stop recommending it?

Comment: try using [day.js](https://day.js.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get (*almost exactly*) the result you want using the `toLocaleDateString()` method in JavaScript. This essentially spits out a date string based on a `Date` object, and you can pass in options to alter the format of the date/time.

There is a more in-depth explaination on the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), but you simply pass in the ***locale*** for the date, and then any options for how to format each part of the date.

```js
const _DateAndTime = () => {
  document.querySelector("#currentTime").innerHTML = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-gb', {year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true});
  document.querySelector("#futureTime").innerHTML = new Date(Date.now()+36e5).toLocaleDateString('en-gb', {year: 'numeric', month: 'short', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true});
}

setInterval(_DateAndTime, 60000);
_DateAndTime();
```

```html
<div id="currentTime"></div>
<div id="futureTime"></div>
```

**Notes**

I am using the `en-gb` locale because it uses the `dd/mm/yyyy` format, as opposed to `en-us` which uses `mm/dd/yyyy`. There are probably other locales that can be used to display the month as ***Sep*** instead of ***Sept***, but it was close enough to where I didn't consider it to be an issue.

Comment: code works however it loads in really late for some reason? i have to wait literally a minute for the date to pop up after i load my page

Comment: @annu The `setInterval` line has the function run once per minute (because seconds are not displayed), but the last line `_DateAndTime();` runs the function immediately. It runs fine here in the StackSnippet so are you sure you fully copied my code (including the last line to run the function immediately)?

Comment: i got it to work in the end by changing the 60000 to 0 lol works perfect now loads instantly in thanks bro, but what if i wanted to minus a few minutes from the current time how would i do that? so if i wanted it to appear as 22 Sept 2022 *current time minus 10 minutes*, the live time always being 10 minutes behind the actual time right now

Comment: @annu Changing the `60000` to `0` means the `setInterval` function runs with an interval of zero. This is bad for performance as the `_DateAndTime()` function is essentially running non-stop with no delay (using up resources unnecessarily). If for some reason `_DateAndTime()` doesn't run when the page loads, you probably have this JavaScript ahead of your HTML (for example, loading in the `<head>` instead of at the end of the `<body>` (*check your browsers console `F12` for errors*).

Comment: @annu As for how to change the time difference, if you look at the second line of the function that updates the `#futureTime` element, you will see `new Date(Date.now()+36e5)`. This is taking `Date.now()` which is the current time and adding 1 hour to it (*in milliseconds*). `36e5` is the same as `3600000`. If you want to take away 10 minutes, you would subtract `600000` (*milliseconds*) or `6e5`.

Answer (score -1):

```js
/**
 * Get am or pm based on hour
 * @param {number} hour
 * @returns {string} am or pm
 */
function getAmPm(hour) {
  return hour >= 12 ? "pm" : "am";
}

/**
 * Get hour in 12 hour format
 * @param {number} hour
 * @returns {number} hour in 12 hour format
 */
function getHour12(hour) {
  return hour % 12 || 12;
}

/**
 * Get the currentDate and currentDate plus 1 hour
 * @returns {{ currentDate: string, currentDatePlus1Hour: string }}
 */
function getDateAndTime() {
  const date = new Date();

  const months = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec",
  ];

  const day = date.getDate();
  const month = date.getMonth();
  const year = date.getFullYear();

  const hour = date.getHours();
  const minute = date.getMinutes();
  const second = date.getSeconds();

  const hourPlusOne = hour + 1;

  const currentDate = `${day} ${months[month]} ${year} ${getHour12(
    hour
  )}:${minute}:${second} ${getAmPm(hour)}`;
  const currentDatePlus1Hour = `${day} ${months[month]} ${year} ${getHour12(
    hourPlusOne
  )}:${minute}:${second} ${getAmPm(hourPlusOne)}`;

  return { currentDate, currentDatePlus1Hour };
}

console.log(getDateAndTime());
```

Comment: There are much easier ways of formatting a date; see the duplicate.